# Keep a program running, even while logged off?

Tags: c#-4.0

I need to run my windows Form Application running while window is logged off i am bound to use windows Form app so i can not use windows service for the solution.

Comment: `i am bound to use windows Form app` - If the requirement is to run something in the background all the time, a WinForms app is the wrong tool for the problem.  What are you trying to accomplish here and what is preventing you from using other solutions?

Comment: Yes Correct. I am trying to accomplish a web scraping app. First I used asp.net (WebRequest mehthod) and made a cron for the job which was working perfectly. But suddenly it stopped working because Web Site was asking for a capcha which I was unable to handle in using webrequest method. So i decided to work with a window app(Using webbrowser control) and enter the capcha manually when ever it asks. Which now I accomplished as well. But Now Problem is that how to run this app on my webserver when it is logged off.